# Update One to Many in EF by searching for Id

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to update the User so I can add a book (the title and author) by simply sending in the Id with HTTP req of the said book and then search for it.  I am not getting the desired results, however, everything seems to work except that as you can see in the picture down below I get back that the book has null values on everything including the title and author which is not the case when I have searched for it, as can be seen on image 2.

```
    // Update user to include a rented book
    public Users Update(Users user)
    {
        var usr = ctx.User
            .Include(s => s.BooksRented)
             .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == user.Id);

        foreach (var bar in user.BooksRented)
        {
            var book = ctx.Book
                .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bar.Id);

            //book.CurrentUser = usr;
            book.UserId = user.Id;
            usr.BooksRented.Add(book);

            //ctx.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        //ctx.Entry(usr).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return usr;
    }
```

---

```
    // Also tried this as suggested, it loops through by adding the user to 
    //  books back and forth until it throws an error.
    public Users Update(Users user)
    {
        Books book = new Books();
        var r = ctx.User
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == user.Id);

        ctx.Entry(r).State = EntityState.Modified;

        foreach (var bar in user.BooksRented)
        {
            book = ctx.Book
                .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bar.Id);
            book.UserId = user.Id;
            ctx.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }


        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return r;
    }
```

---

```
public class Books
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool InRent { get; set; }
    public Users CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime Released { get; set; }
    public DateTime RentedDate { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Books> BooksRented { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(a => a.BooksRented)
            .WithOne(r => r.CurrentUser)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);

 }
```

[image: Postman]
[image: my search result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if it is EF, you need foreign keys UserId in books

2) you return the user that you yourself sent to the method

3) What is it? You save the same object from database, that you received from the database

```
 Books book = new Books();
        foreach (var bar in user.BooksRented)
        {
            book = ctx.Book
                .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bar.Id);
        }
        ctx.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I guess it will work with something like this:

1) add UserId in Books

```
    public class Books
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool InRent { get; set; }
    public Users CurrentUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime Released { get; set; }
    public DateTime RentedDate { get; set; }

    public int UserId {get; set;]
}
```

2) Change main code to something like:

```
   public Users RentBook(Users user)
{
    var r = ctx.User
        .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == user.Id); 

    ctx.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

    foreach (var bar in user.BooksRented)
    {
        book = ctx.Book
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bar.Id);
        book.UserId = user.Id;
        ctx.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }


    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return r.Include(x => x.BooksRented);
}
```

This is also not entirely ideal, but I think it will work. The only thing is not entirely sure about the last line.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have returned the user there, that was an oversight, I forgot also to add the OnModelCreating in the context where I have included a foreign key.  The suggestion you provided didn't quite work.  Now I am continuously looping back and forth by adding Users to BooksRented until it throws an error.    I have updated my query in the OP.

Comment: 1) Instead OnModelCreating, you can use [ForeignKey("")] in model 2) Your new code is work now? 3) In new code you add books parameters, after selected it in loop. If one user will have 2 or more books, it will not work currect.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it doesn't quite work still, it seems I need to .Add(book) somehow to the property List<BooksRented>, otherwise, it keeps giving me null value.  I am basically just searching for user and then modifying the user itself. The child value within the user never gets modified though, I am not sure how to add it without giving an error.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work now, I had to remove Users CurrentUsers from the model, it was causing a loop.  And I have updated the OP with what seems to work.  Thanks for your inputs. :)